# Values from javascript is not presenting in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm about to send out JSON data using Javascript to HTML.

Let say my JSON data from API is like below.

[image]

and my code is like below

```
<script>
async function load(){
      let link = 'Here is API address';
      let data = await fetch(link);
      let obj = await data.json();

      var temp = "";
      for(var a=1; a<45; a++){
          temp += "<tr>";
          for(var b=0; b<5; b++){
            temp += `<td>${obj[`Tool${a}[${b}]`]}</td>`;
          }
      }
      document.getElementById("data_from_db").innerHTML = temp;
  }
  load();
</script>
```

However it seems like it didn't work because the outcome is like below

[image]

Could you let me know what is wrong in my code?

Thank you!!

*** Added ***

I'm not sure but Undefined meant there is a correct variables but there is no value in it.
However I don't know why and API works well because the screen capture above is when I put API URL at the browser

Comment: Can you try by changing the line to temp += `<td>${obj['Tool'+a][b]}</td>`;

Comment: Unfortunately not working, even undefined fields are not appear

Comment: It is because the code to render the data in table works before the API completes

Comment: Or you can make it as a promise, so that you can use the .then() callback to check if the API execution completed or not.

Comment: FYI, the `tr` is not closed after each line.

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `${obj[\`Tool${a}\`][b]}`. The square brackets are turning into string bits instead of dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved array is part of object.. it should be like below.
Both are working

```
temp += `<td>${obj[`Tool${a}`][b]}</td>`;
temp += '<td>' + obj[`Tool${a}`][b] + '</td>';
```